# Rust - true or false

Tags: rust, boolean

How does one properly read from user input a string ('true' or 'false')  as bool - true or false, and do something with that? Without this primitive way by using `len()`?

```
fn main() {
    loop {
        println!("Input condition - true or false");

        let mut condition = String::new();

        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut condition)
            .expect("failed to read input.");

        let len = calculate_length(&condition);

        // println!("The length of '{}' is {}.\n", &condition, &len);

        fn calculate_length(condition: &String) -> usize {
            condition.len()
        }

        match len == 5 {
            true => {
                let number = 100;
                println!("The value of number is: {}", &number);
            }

            _ => {
                let number = 7;
                println!("The value of number is: {}", &number);
            }
        };

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is independent of Rust or any specific programming language - there's no obvious "canonical" way to turn a String into a boolean value. Exactly which strings counts as true, and which as false - and what if the user types a random string like, for example, "kylj"? You need to decide on your own logic and implement that - for example preceding one way if the input is "true", another if it is "false", and prompting the user again for "proper" input if it is anything else.

Comment: @RobinZigmond there is a `FromStr` implementation for `bool`, which seems like a pretty canonical way to turn a string into a boolean.

Comment: @IvanC - fair point, I just looked it up. I'm not familiar enough with Rust and forgot that it had traits with associated types, which make this a much more sensible idea than it would be with most other languages. Although I still maintain it's fairly arbitrary - it seems that it is happy converting "true" and "false", but what about eg "True" and "False"? What if you want say "t" and "f", or "1" and "0", to also count? While it seems convenient that Rust has this, it won't always replace the need to write your own logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
let truth_value: bool = match condition {
   "true" => true,
   "t" => true,
   "false" => false,
   "f" => false,
   ... any other cases you want
   _ => false  // Or whatever appropriate default value or error.
}
```

Then you `truth_value` variable will be a boolean. Typically this sort of functionality is embedded in a `FromStr` implementation, but it needn't be, strictly speaking.

Comment: This can be shortened to `let truth_value = matches!(condition, "true" | "t" | "1")`

Comment: Thank you all, seniors in coding, for all your contributions. Maybe it was a “small question”, but it was really nice receive your answers.  It was really helpful to have your input.

Answer (score 8):

Rust has a native `FromStr` implementation for many types, including `bool`, that is frequently invoked via [`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse):

```rust
if condition.trim().parse().unwrap() {
    // true branch
} else {
    // false branch
}
```

This implementation only matches on the exact strings `"true"` and `"false"`, so it is more suitable for deserialization than user interaction.  In particular, it is necessary to remove the newline at the end of `condition` (using `.trim()`) before parsing.

The use of `unwrap` here is for demonstration only — see [the Error Handling chapter of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) for more on the information on error handling in Rust.

---

After you become more familiar with Rust, you can use crates like [`dialoguer`](https://docs.rs/dialoguer) to  render select prompts:

```rust
use dialoguer::Select;

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let selection = Select::new().item("Choice 1").item("Choice 2").interact()?;

    match selection {
        0 => eprintln!("Choice 1 was selected."),
        1 => eprintln!("Choice 2 was selected."),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

(using `anyhow` for error handling)